# Android Java - Using custom adapter with ListView Select a checkbox and another row item also selected

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using an arrayList, Custom Adapter and ListView (using Text and Image to indicate the item is selected when a ListView item is clicked). The image that changes has the same function as a checkbox, so when clicked it changes to a tick and changes to a cross when clicked a second time etc...

Everything is working as expected except when I click the row to indicate the item  has been selected which works, however the issue is that another item a few rows down seems to also be selected which was not my intention. I have read alot of posts in regards to recylerViews and ViewHolder but they don't seem to work.

Here is a sample of my code;

```
public void myList() { 
    Info.add(new Stored("Name", 2000, R.drawable.pic1, "My details", false));
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Stored> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.myLayout, Info);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listlayout11, parent, false);
        }

        // Have defined items to be displayed here
    }

private void myonClickItem() {
    final ListView myList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listVierMain);  
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {   

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id)  {   

       Stored clickedItem1 = Info.get(position);
       String currentValItem = ((TextView) viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.item5)).getText().toString();

       clickedItem1.SelectedSetter(currentValItem, viewClicked); 


 }


  // Setter used to set data to arrayList
  public void SelectedSetter(String wasItClicked, View viewClicked)
{
    ImageView checkedImage = (ImageView) viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxIMG);  // Create new object and assign to control

    if (wasItClicked.equals("false")) {
        this.itemChecked = true;
        checkedImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.CheckedPic);
    }
    else{
        this.itemChecked = false;
        checkedImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.unCheckedPic);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you better upload also the code relative to `onItemClick()` method. The problem could be there!

Answer (score 0):

Its not an issue, its android pattern. U are telling android adapter that if ur view its not null to inflate a row. Well ur view at that position its not null and android reuse the row u created in the first. Its how adapter list works in android.

Comment: By removing the null check the imageView does seem to change on click. From what I can see you are correct it is the way the layout is reused. I have simply removed the if (itemView == null) { } check so only the below is shown;
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listlayout11, parent, false);